# Does Google index other answer pages (page > 1) of long threads?

Tags: discussion, seo, indexing

I had a liberty of experimenting with two "heavy-weight" questions:

[What's the most egregious pop culture perversion of programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175074/whats-the-most-egregious-pop-culture-perversion-of-programming)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140270/humor-in-code

If I copy out some specific content from the following pages and try to google for it limiting to site:stackoverflow.com, I don't find a direct link to the answer only to some mobile page containing all answers at once.

I'm curious is that *by design* or something that was forgotten or considered unimportant?

If this is so *intentionally*, may I ask why?